# Sorting Alphanumeric Lists by Character Detection (python)

Tags: python, sorting

I'm making a program that is able to open a zip file and list off the file names in alphanumeric order. Here's my code:

```
import zipfile
import re

zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile('/home/aaaa/exploit/example.zip','r')
  for name in zip_file.namelist():
  sorted(str(name in zip_file.namelist()))
    print(name)

zip_file.close()
```

And here's the output:

```
example/
example/txt2.txt
example/txt3.txt
example/txt1.txt
```

I would like name in `zip_file.namelist()` to be organized as such:

```
example/
example/txt1.txt
example/txt2.txt
example/txt3.txt
```

but I'm not very sure how to sort alphanumeric strings like this by the number only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't sorting the list before you loop through them. Try this:

```
for name in sorted(zip_file.namelist()):
    print(name)
```

Comment: p e r f e c t  t y

Answer (score 0):

`namelist` points to an internal object filelist. You can try to sort the output data: `sorted(zip_file.namelist())`, or either you can touch the internal object `zip_file.filelist.sort()` instead.